# How to do jQuery AJAX requests with Facebook C# SDK and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to do a jQuery AJAX call to my MVC controller in my [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) Canvas application with something like:

```
$('#btnGetInfo').click(function () {
   $.getJSON("/Home/GetInfo", null, 
   function (result) {

   });
   return false;
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetInfo()
{
  // do some Facebook call 
  var fb = new FacebookClient();
  dynamic albums = fb.Get(string.Format("/{0}/photos", friendID));
}
```

I then get `(OAuthException) An access token is required to request this resource` , which I suppose is more or less expected. So I try to decorate the method:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,user_photos,.....)]
public ActionResult GetInfo()
{
   ...
}
```

But then the method is never called from the page.

With the sample project from CodePlex, putting the code in the Index() home controller works, so it's not a configuration issue, not in the app nor in the Facebook settings.
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with persisting auth info thru post backs. Perhaps the `CanvasAuthorizer` class should be involved somehow, maybe the `signed_request` things? I'm new to FB programming and having a hard time putting the pieces together...

Update: If I call my method using a standard

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("DoThis", "GetInfo", "Home")%>
```

call, the method executes correctly (with a signed_request), so the question is now;
How can I do a jQuery call to my ASP.NET MVC controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to [post the signed_request data](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/251878) in the ajax call (thanks ntotten):

```
$.getJSON('/Home/GetInfo',  { "signed_request": '<%=Request.Params["signed_request"] %>' },
            function (result) {
                alert("Done");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the Facebook variables in your web.config? You might want to use NuGet to reference the project as Prabir (one of the main SDK developers) has wired up the NuGet package to autoconfigure your web.config with the custom config items (you still need to have a Facebook Application and wire up the config with all the necessary additional information like your app secret and app id (those are the main 2 things you need)

Comment: Sure, been there, done that. It's not a configuration issue, Q updated.